# Model/Infographic of plane of orbits and rotations planes of solar bodies (including their moons)

Tags: solar-system, modeling

Is there a model/infographic with emphasis on the orbit and rotation plane of solar bodies? Of course, no scaling is needed for the size or distance. I remember reading there is one planet where the axis of its rotation is almost parallel to plane of its orbit.

Comment: I don't know if you can find exactly what you are looking for, but you can check out [Collection of space exploration related infographics](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/12102) in Space Exploration SE meta

Comment: I noticed that your profile says "...Math,Coding, Physics and anything brainy" and you are active in Math SE. The following question has a bounty that expires in 10 hours plus a 24 hour grace period.[Determine if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619)

Comment: @uhoh : thank you , that question requires much more knowledge than I have.

Comment: ya I was surprised but even with a bounty there's been no answers, perhaps there is no easy way to do it. Thanks for having a look!